# How to rotate icon continuous? (Keyframes not working)

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, css-animations

I've tried to make my `icon` rotate continuous like following, but it's not rotating or doing anything.

I know that there are similar questions about this topic, but each solution in there are not working out for me.

I'm working with `Vue 3`, `Bootstrap 5.3` and `Chrome`.

What's wrong in here? Thanks for your help!

```css
.rotating-icon {
  animation: transform-icon 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes transform-icon {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg) !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-b6lVK+yci+bfDmaY1u0zE8YYJt0TZxLEAFyYSLHId4xoVvsrQu3INevFKo+Xir8e" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="col-1">
    <i class="bi bi-hourglass-top rotating-icon"></i>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet and removed the template which will make it invisible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to make the element  `display: inline-block;` and you can not have the important in the rules.

```css
.rotating-icon {
  animation: transform-icon 5s infinite linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes transform-icon {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-b6lVK+yci+bfDmaY1u0zE8YYJt0TZxLEAFyYSLHId4xoVvsrQu3INevFKo+Xir8e" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-1">
  <i class="bi bi-hourglass-top rotating-icon"></i>
</div>
```